# How to define a Map in a YAML file in the Play! framework?

Tags: java, playframework, snakeyaml

I'm using the Play! framework and I have a model (an Entity) that has a variable of type Map.

To make some tests, I load a YAML file every time I start the application, but I don't know the syntax to define a Map.

Let's say I have this class

```
public class aClass {
    public int arg1;
    public String arg2;
    public Map<String, Integer> arg3;
}
```

What would my YAML file look like? I tried this:

```
aClass(object1)
    arg1:   34
    arg2:   aString
    arg3:   [key1: value1, key2: value2] <- What do I do here?
```

This is one of my many tries. I don't know the syntax and I can't find it on the Internet. I think the Play! uses SnakeYAML as YAML parser.

In the doc I found some examples, but none of them will work.

In my application, everything works except that the Map variable (arg3 in the example) has a size of 0 element.

Thanks.

Comment: According to SnakeYAML documentation, and Play documentation, the correct notation is to use question marks. However, I have tried to run your code in this way, and although it compiles, it has no entries! I will keep digging.

Comment: Does it work when you use the question marks?

Comment: I tried again using the question marks. It does compile, but my Map returns null when I try to get the value of one of the keys specified in the YAML file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this thread on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/play-framework/yaml%2420map/play-framework/61FfT3RKbtw/9z0g8sibgpUJ) it appears that the syntax you need is to use a question mark.

The thread has a working map in the following syntax.

```
Bloc(b2): 
  labelSeries: testDeValeur 
  criterias: 
    ? key1 
    : value1 
    ? key2 
    : value2
```

So, I guess your example would be

```
aClass(object1)
  arg1:   34
  arg2:   aString
  arg3:   
    ? key1
    : value1
    ? key2
    : value2
```

I have tested this however and it does not work! I would suggest raising a bug to take a look into this, because all documentation points at this being correct.

Comment: I corrected my question. But I found the exact same thread on Google Groups and it didn't work...

Comment: So this doesn't work, but is the accepted answer! WAT?